# Filtering with OR and taking only one row if both restrictions are satisfied

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE #events (vehicleid int, time datetime, contextid nvarchar(20), value nvarchar(10))

INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 10:40:52.777', 'TwigStatus', '5')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:07:44.740', 'ConnectionLost', 'True')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:07:44.777', 'TwigStatus', '4')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:17:48.647', 'ConnectionLost', 'False')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:17:48.777', 'TwigStatus', '5')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:26:52.000', 'TwigStatus', '4')

SELECT * FROM #events
```

This gives the following output:

[image]

Now, I'm surpised myself to not have been confronted to this problem until now:

The 2 events in yellow and in red are tied to each other (they have the same semantics, only one of them or both could be present in the data set). So I would like to have a SELECT QUERY that will return only one of them if both are present, and the one present if only one is, just by using the `contextid` and `value` columns in the restriction(s). The time column is not relevant for filtering, just for ordering the final resultset though.

Obviously, a simple `OR` clause does not work for that, as it will return both records. What are my options here?

I can't wrap my head over improving this query to do what I need:

```
SELECT * FROM #events
WHERE ( (contextId = 'TwigStatus' and value = '4' ) OR (contextid = 'ConnectionLost' AND value = 'True') ) OR ( (contextId = 'TwigStatus' and value = '5' ) OR (contextid = 'ConnectionLost' AND value = 'False') )
```

---

**UPDATE**: Expected output with different sets of data:

```
CREATE TABLE #events (vehicleid int, time datetime, contextid nvarchar(20), value nvarchar(10))

INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 10:40:52.777', 'TwigStatus', '5')
--INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:07:44.740', 'ConnectionLost', 'True')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:07:44.777', 'TwigStatus', '4')
--INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:17:48.647', 'ConnectionLost', 'False')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:17:48.777', 'TwigStatus', '5')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:26:52.000', 'TwigStatus', '4')

SELECT * FROM #events
```

[image]

OR

```
CREATE TABLE #events (vehicleid int, time datetime, contextid nvarchar(20), value nvarchar(10))

INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 10:40:52.777', 'TwigStatus', '5')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:07:44.740', 'ConnectionLost', 'True')
--INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:07:44.777', 'TwigStatus', '4')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:17:48.647', 'ConnectionLost', 'False')
--INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:17:48.777', 'TwigStatus', '5')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:26:52.000', 'TwigStatus', '4')

SELECT * FROM #events
```

[image]

OR

```
CREATE TABLE #events (vehicleid int, time datetime, contextid nvarchar(20), value nvarchar(10))

INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 10:40:52.777', 'TwigStatus', '5')
--INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:07:44.740', 'ConnectionLost', 'True')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:07:44.777', 'TwigStatus', '4')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:17:48.647', 'ConnectionLost', 'False')
--INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:17:48.777', 'TwigStatus', '5')
INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:26:52.000', 'TwigStatus', '4')

SELECT * FROM #events
```

[image]

Comment: Your database model is wrong if you have data that should not be there by definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use analytical function `row_number` as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by vehicleid, CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), time ,20) AS datetime) 
                         order by time) as rn
  From your_table t
 Where t.contextid in ('ConnectionLost','TwigStatus') ) t
 Where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, try to avoid using reserved keyword like `time` and `value` when creating your columns.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE events (vehicleid int, time datetime, contextid nvarchar(20), value nvarchar(10))
>
> INSERT INTO events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 10:40:52.777', 'TwigStatus', '5')
> --INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:07:44.740', 'ConnectionLost', 'True')
> INSERT INTO events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:07:44.777', 'TwigStatus', '4')
> INSERT INTO events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:17:48.647', 'ConnectionLost', 'False')
> --INSERT INTO #events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:17:48.777', 'TwigStatus', '5')
> INSERT INTO events VALUES (26605, '2021-01-11 11:26:52.000', 'TwigStatus', '4')
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```

4 rows affected

> 

> ```
> WITH CTE AS
> (SELECT e.vehicleid, CONVERT(CHAR(10), e.[time], 23) + ' ' + 
>     RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), e.[time], 22), 11)), 11) AS [time],e.contextid, e.[value]
>        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY 
>                           e.vehicleid
>                           , CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), e.time ,20) AS datetime )
>
>                           order by e.[time]) as rn
>   FROM events e
>  WHERE e.contextid IN ('ConnectionLost' , 'TwigStatus'))
> SELECT * FROM CTE
> WHERE rn =1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> vehicleid | time                   | contextid      | value | rn
> --------: | :--------------------- | :------------- | :---- | -:
>     26605 | 2021-01-11 10:40:52 AM | TwigStatus     | 5     |  1
>     26605 | 2021-01-11 11:07:44 AM | TwigStatus     | 4     |  1
>     26605 | 2021-01-11 11:17:48 AM | ConnectionLost | False |  1
>     26605 | 2021-01-11 11:26:52 AM | TwigStatus     | 4     |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3772940ed083fe29077d0e3efa98f5d9)*

Comment: The time column is not relevant for filtering, just for ordering the final resultset though.